# Exploring a loan data set when I'm interested in change in number of loans over time, not acceptance/rejection, defaulting, etc

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, modeling, exploratory-data-analysis

This is a simple question but I am having difficulty wrapping my head around it. I have a dataset listing a bunch of individual loans. There are tens of variables describing aspects of the loans, mix of categorical and quantitative. I am interested in studying the influence of these different variables on the *change in number of loans over time* (month-to-month). That is, how do these variables relate to total number of loans given out on a monthly basis?

I am used to studying loan data sets where I predict defaulting or loan approval or similar, but this is new to me.

There are too many variables to use ggpairs or similar. Where does my data exploration start? How should I go about approaching this problem? Do I group loans by month and look for relationships between variables within?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable you are trying to explain is an aggregate variable.

You have to aggregate the loan characteristics (try different summary statistics: sum, mean, median and a few other quantiles, higher moments etc.) and try to tease out a relationship between the loan count and these aggregated characteristics.

You might have to add macroeconomic variables to the mix too as the number of loans gets influenced by the macroeconomy too.

Comment: Would it help for me to do clustering within each month to see if different variables are related to one another?

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea if you have a large number of independent variables and want to see if there's some lower-dimensional latent factor structure driving the independent variables.